# R.java not generating

Tags: android, eclipse

I know there have been several problems like this, but in all of the threads that I have seen the problem is that the .xml files contain errors(or are named with capital letters or something).

In my case, eclipse won't even generate a R.java when I create a new project that only includes the standard "hello world" example files.

I have restarted, re-installed and recreated projects, but nothing seems to work so in my desperation I am hoping someone has seen a similar problem and knows a solution.

Comment: Forgot to mention, have also tried to "Clean" the project with no luck

Comment: What OS are you using? Creating R.java implies creating the gen directory as well, so it might be insufficient permissions for your IDE.

Comment: have you installed ADT plugin

Comment: and every other things properly

Comment: I updated the adk plugin today, then I had the same issue. Turned out that after the update, two new updates were waiting. After installing those, everything went back to normal.

Comment: Have you just upgraded to ADT 22?

Answer (score 2):

If you run a clean on the project it should regenerate all the generated java files, namely R.

In Eclipse, under the Project menu, is an option build automatically. That would help you build the R.java file every time modifications are made. The Clean... option is also there under Project.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a very similar problem upon upgrading the version of my Android Development Tools to 22.  The solution was to install all updates for ADT by opening...

```
Help -> Install New Software
```

... and using the update site...

```
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

... to install all outstanding Developer Tools updates.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks for answering.

It turned out that after installing the ADT, some SDK packages had not installed, (even though I distinctly remember choosing to install them). I installed those packages and everything seems to be working fine.

Thank you